# Cloning a test case within the same test suite, in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

How can I clone a test case within a test suite, so that the test case shows up in the same test suite?

This is on azure-devops.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Hey Hugh Lin - MSFT, yes this worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue ,you can first `Open test case`, then `Create copy of work item`, finally add this copied test case to the test suite.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if this works and will let you know.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you , you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day :)